# Joining a standard output and susbtitution thereof into table

Tags: io-redirection, tee, tr, paste

Say I have:

```
$ cat tmp1.txt
a
b
c
```

Then

```
$ paste tmp1.txt <(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'<tmp1.txt)
a   A
b   B
c   C
```

How would I modify the above to

1/ invoke `tmp1.txt` only once? (I suspect `tee`)

2/ supply the content of `tmp1.txt` from the terminal (as if produced by the output from a command). For this, I tried to tinker with this but did not go very far:

```
$ cat<< 'EOF' | tee >(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
a
b
c
EOF
```

which outputs:

```
a
b
c
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a named pipe to create an additional channel for data between `tee` and `tr`:

```
$ mkfifo pipe
$ tee pipe <file | paste - <( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <pipe )
a       A
b       B
c       C
```

Alternatively (but not as nice looking), moving the `tr` to the left of the `|`:

```
$ mkfifo pipe
$ tee >( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' >pipe ) <file | paste - pipe
```

You need the extra named pipe to be able to give the data transformed by `tr` to `paste`.  The `paste` utility needs to read two streams, the original data and the transformed data.  One of these can be a standard stream while the other needs to come from either the original file (reading the file a second time) or a named pipe as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution using *awk*

```
awk ' { print $0 , toupper($0) ; } ' /tmp/tmp1.txt
```

or

```
( echo a ; echo b ; echo c ;  ) | awk ' { print $0 , toupper($0) ; } '
```

or by using named piped or fifo

```
( echo a ; echo b ; echo c ) |
(
  D=$(mktemp -d) ;
  (
    cd $D ;
    mkfifo fifo_a fifo_b ;
    paste fifo_b <( tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < fifo_a ) &
    tee  fifo_a  > fifo_b  ;
    wait ;
    rm fifo_a fifo_b
  ) ;
  rmdir $D
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This may ultimately be what I will be use, but I'm still interested in the `paste`+`tee` approach so I can fill my knowledge gap at that intersection.